# Regex don't include match after captured group

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy, regex-group

I'm trying to extract variables from less css pre-processor source code file by using a regular expression, but my question can be asked more generally.

I need to craft a regular expression that works like this:

- *input*: `@one: cat` *output*: `cat`
- *input*: `@one: dog;` *output*: `dog`

Note the final semi-colon after 'dog' that I wish to not capture.

I have this almost working with: `new RegExp('^.*:\\s*(.*?);?');`

But my final `;?` isn't being excluded from the match `(.*?)`.

How do I make my selection be less greedy?

JsBin: http://jsbin.com/ludaqogexa/edit?js,console

Comment: Do you really need to do a string replace, or are you trying to set the string to only the captured group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making them "less greedy" is done by adding a `?` after the quantifier as you did. The problem is that you haven't added an end anchor `$` - if you add that your regex will work as expected. The behavior in that corner case depends on the regex engine; the .NET engine for instance would only match a single character in that case (`d` for the `dog` case) and stop.

However, this is not the solution IMHO. You should describe the pattern more precisely and then it will even work with the greedy matching.

```
/^[^:]+:\s*([^;]+);?/;
```

Comment: Do you happen to know why OP original attempts isn't working though? I am interested... why is the `'` part of the capture group?

Comment: @musefan Edited with an explanation of the problem in the original regex.

Comment: @Lucero thank you, nice explanation and a better approach